# Disable semicolon path paramaters in Tomcat to prevent access to secured folders (security vulnerabilty)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

### The problem

Lets say I have an "admin" application (`admin.war`) deployed on a Tomcat server. There is a view that by design is accessible like this:

```bash
https://example.com/admin/secret-icons/
```

Tomcat is behind a proxy that is Apache Httpd and that proxy has access control on the folder `/admin/secret-icons/`.

Is there a simple way to disable this as valid routes to the same view?

```bash
https://example.com/;security-breach=1;/admin/secret-icons/
https://example.com/;breach/admin/;breach/secret-icons/
https://example.com/;breach/admin;breach/secret-icons/
https://example.com/admin;breach/secret-icons/
https://example.com/admin;whatever/secret-icons/
https://example.com/admin;/secret-icons/
```

Is there some configuration in Tomcat or Java code that can disable using `;param=1` in the middle of the request URI? So that the view can only by accessed with `/admin/secret-icons` as a base path? I would be happy even if at least context path (`/admin/`) would be preserved.

### Details

Note that the path parameters just work on the Servlet level in Java. Nothing in our application enabled them, we don't use this specific type of the path parameters at all. Note that W3C calls this [Matrix URIs](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html).

This is the access control used in httpd:

```
<Location /admin/secret-icons>
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 10.17.0.5
        Require ip 88.11.22.33
    </RequireAny>
</Location>
```

The proxy connects to Tomcat with AJP if that matters. Apache Httpd is actually behind another caching proxies, but that shouldn't matter. I think this is a Java problem (frankly I don't know who thought this was a good idea to have params inside random places of the path).

This is Java code for the `/secret-icons` route (in `admin.war`):

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class AdminController {
    // ...
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "secret-icons")
    public String showIcons(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // ...
        return "icons";
    }
```

If that is important this is a Spring Framework (*not* Boost) application. So if there is something in Spring configuration or some code or annotation to use to disable this completely or specifically (for specific route) that would all be fine by me. I would prefer to disable this as high as possible though.